# Highlight a time range in a DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I want to do a datelistplot with a temporal data, and then i want to highlight in the plot an interval of data between two dates. the highlight i want to do is put a rectangle behind the plot.

I tried to run an example but didnt work

```
data = FinancialData["AAPL", "Jan. 1, 2021"];
plot = DateListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue];

highlight = {{DateObject[{2021, 3, 1}], DateObject[{2021, 6, 1}], 
    Directive[Red, Opacity[0.2]]}, {DateObject[{2021, 9, 1}], 
    DateObject[{2021, 12, 1}], Directive[Green, Opacity[0.2]]}};

Show[plot, Epilog -> Rectangle @@@ highlight]
```

kind regards

Answer (score 8):

One solution:

```
    plot = DateListPlot[
             {data,
              TimeSeriesWindow[data, {DateObject[{2021, 3, 1}], DateObject[{2021, 6, 1}]}], 
              TimeSeriesWindow[data, {DateObject[{2021, 9, 1}], DateObject[{2021, 12, 1}]}]}, 
              PlotStyle -> Blue,
              Filling -> {
                 None, 
                 2 -> {Axis, Directive[Red, Opacity[0.2]]}, 
                 3 -> {Axis, Directive[Green, Opacity[0.2]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is a interesting way to do it!

Answer (score 7):

#### 1.

```
Show[plot, 
 Epilog -> ({#3, Rectangle[{#, 0}, {#2, First @ Max @ data}]} & @@@
   (highlight /. d_DateObject :> AbsoluteTime[d]))]
```

[image]

#### 2.

```
DateListPlot[{data, ## & @@ (Thread[{{#, #2}, Max@data}] & @@@ highlight)}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, None, None}, 
 Filling -> MapThread[{# -> {Axis, #2}} &]@{{2, 3}, highlight[[All, -1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks the first one seems simple for me. kind regards